# SCSF Calling services asynchronously

Tags: .net, cab, smartclient, scsf

Are there any best practices for calling SCSF services asynchronously?

**Particularly I'm interesting in:**

- Executions of requests in background
- Cancellation support
- Reporting progress

**Currently I came up with two scenarios:**

1. Listener Service which listens in background for real-time updates
   and displays received data in grid (displaying stock quotes in
   real-time);
2. Long-running request, which supports cancellation, progress reporting and returns data incrementally.